# FORMS, no further idea how to implement a TextField with a CupertinoApp

Tags: forms, flutter, state, flutter-cupertino

This drives me nuts. I am trying to get a `CupertinoTextField` into a `Form`. But no matter what I try, everything turns out as a dead end.

The complication of my case is, the form in embedded into the [Flushbar](https://pub.dev/packages/flushbar) package, which provides kind of a snackbar to my CupertinoApp. And this is a stateless widget ;-(

```dart
 return Flushbar(
      backgroundColor: Common.inputBlue,
      userInputForm : Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
            children: <Widget> [
              _DelayStatusFormField(
                initialValue: task.delayStatus,
                onSaved: (value) => otherFormDataSubmit.delayStatus = value,
                //onSaved: (value) => this.delayStatus = value,
              ),
              CupertinoTextField(
                controller: _delayTec,
                onChanged: (text) {
                  state.didChange(text);
                },
              ),
            ]),
         ),
 );
```

In the onChanged section I intend to implement some validation, so I need kind of a rebuild.  But setState obviously doesn't work without a proper state.

Using TextFormField also looks kind of dodgy, because I do not only have to embed this in `Material(` but in loads of further localization Widgets.

The most desirable solution, is this one where I tried several variants: embed the CupertinoTextField in a FormField class

```dart
class _DelayFormField extends FormField<String> {
  _DelayFormField({
    FormFieldSetter<String> onSaved,
    String initialValue,
    bool enabled,
    GlobalKey key,
  }) : super(
      onSaved: onSaved,
      initialValue: initialValue,
      key: key,
      builder: (FormFieldState<String> state) {
        //TextEditingController inputTec = TextEditingController(text: initialValue);
        return Column(children: [
          SizedBox(
              width: 100, height: 30,
              child: CupertinoTextField(
                //controller: inputTec,
                enabled: true,
                onChanged: (text) {
                  initialValue = text;
                  state.didChange(text);
                },
              )),
        ]);
      }
  );
}
```

The problem here, I the TextEditingController is reinitialized on any rebuild with `initialVale`, loosing my input. I have got around this by assigning the input to `initialVale`, but the cursor is then always set leading to the prefilled digits. So you type the number backwards. Since everything is in the class' initialization, I cannot find a spot where to initialize the TextEditingController outside of the build method.

Any other idea on how to solve this? Getting such a class working would be great, since one could then simply re-use this class, frequently.

Comment: Did you try the StatefulBuilder widget?

Comment: Thanks, no I didn't. Meanwhile I replaced the TexField to a Slider, which works well with FormField. One thing I also tried was to adapt TextFormField by copying its code into an own class and replacing the wrapped TextField with CupertinoTextField, but for some reason I did not get it working. Maybe that is why there is no CupertinoTextFormField...